# Does blood pressure increase during deliberate period of focus?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience

Does blood pressure increase during a deliberate period of focus?

My reason for formulating this hypothesis is personal experience.

A simple example is when I work, sitting, at the PC. Let's say I work 25-45 minutes. When I am working my breathing becomes more shallow and it's always through my nose. Then, when I've completed the work I usually, automatically, take a deep breath ... as I physically feel relieved it's over even if it's work I enjoy. Then I notice I am a tiny bit **lightheaded** and, as I feel relieved, and I don't particularly want to get up, I usually have a desire to surf the web.

So, I'm wondering if *concentration causes blood pressure to increase, which then quickly reduces when I'm done with my task*, which is causing this feeling I am describing as *lightheadedness*. Alternatively is the blood pressure change related to the reduced breathing as I focus? ... is there such a thing?

Comment: I edited this question for you so it may remain open. It remains a bit unclear to me why the following is relevant: _"and, as I feel relieved, and I don't particularly want to get up, I usually have a desire to surf the web."_ Is this truly information which makes you ask this question? If so, could you clarify? The underlying assumption seems to be that 'an increase and quick decrease of blood pressure causes lightheadedness'. Could you state this explicitly in case this is what you assume? If so, including a reference explaining why you believe this would improve this question.

Comment: @StevenJeuris Yes, that's exactly why I'm asking the question. I have no idea what clarification is needed. "The underlying assumption seems to be that 'an increase and quick decrease of blood pressure causes lightheadedness'." Yes, that's the question. I have no references. I am asking for references.

Why is it a problem to ask "does concentration causes blood pressure to increase"?

Comment: In regards to 'why': I just wondered, what is the connection between wanting to surf the web and blood pressure? In regards to the assumption which I have now made explicit for you: **"Could you state this explicitly in case this is what you assume?** (which you now have confirmed you do)

Comment: Do you feel excited, stressed or overstimulated while working? Adrenaline causes a temporary rise in blood pressure.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson Yes.